# How can I import other Stack modules in ghci script?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-stack

I have a sequence of IO actions to run before I can explore data in GHCI. So I use this command:

```
stack ghci --ghci-options "-ghci-script Scratch.hs"
```

The problem is that other modules are not found and cannot be imported. They are compiled later though and subsequently can be imported interactively. How can I change this order?

Answer (score 1):

you could write a project specific `.ghci` file:

### `.ghci`

```
import qualified Data.Text as T

:set prompt "Custom GHCi Script > "
:set -XOverloadedStrings

putStrLn "Hello Darkness my old Friend!"
```

then remove all write permissions for non owner

```
$ > chmod go-w .ghci
```

and finally

```
$ > stack ghci
```

or

```
$ > stack ghci --package text --load Scratch.hs
Configuring GHCi with the following packages:
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Hello Darkness my old Friend!
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/epsilonhalbe/.ghci
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/epsilonhalbe/.ghc/ghci.conf
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/ghci24482/ghci-script
Custom GHCi Script > a = T.pack "Text"
Custom GHCi Script > :t a
a :: T.Text
Custom GHCi Script >
```

Comment: Try adding a Foo.hs module to your project and import it's functions. There is no problem in using pre-compiled libraries.

Comment: @sevo you mean a Foo module that is not listed anywhere?

Comment: It needs to be listed as part of the stack project. Otherwise it won't get compiled by GHCI. In my case it is listed in `other-modules` section as well as located under `source-dirs` in `package.yaml`.

Comment: if it is in the "other-modules" section and not in the "exposed-modules" section of your `.cabal` file it won't be imported if you do `stack ghci` - I am a bit confused - is this answer not addressing your problem? are your comments just additions to my answer?

Comment: I can import module without "expsed-modules" using "import Foo" interactively AFTER scripts are loaded. The `-ghci-script Scratch.hs` is just like your solution, except I can have many project specific scripts. The answer is not addressing my problem. My coments try to explain why.

Comment: you can have a `.ghci` file in each project - but if my answer is not addressing your problem, I am sorry. Though I have to say your question is quite short and could use some clarification. Nevertheless I think my answer is useful for someone else, so I won't delete it.